# How to debug bar code scanner on android studio?

Tags: android, debugging, barcode, barcode-scanner

what I am trying to is being able to debug the process of reading a bar code using a bar scan pistol. The app I develop is for tablet and the bar scanner is conected to the tablet, but when the tablet is conected to the pc, the scanner does not work. Any help or suggestions on what to look for? the scanner event I have is

```
String barcode = "";
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {

    if(e.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        char pressedKey = (char) e.getUnicodeChar();
        barcode += pressedKey;
    }
    if (e.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        String search = searchProducts.getText().toString();
        if(search.equals("")){
            barcode = barcode.replaceAll("\\n+", "");
            barcode= barcode.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
            loadProductsByBarCode(barcode);
            barcode="";

        }
    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
}
```

any help or sugestions would be great, thanks

Comment: It might be better to change the scanner to a Bluetooth model and try keyboard emulation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you mean by change to bluetooth? unfortunately I can not connect the scanner via bluetooth if that's what you are saying

Comment: For example, when debugging, the USB port may be occupied to connect to the development host PC. Then there will be no port to connect the barcode scanner. However, since there is a wireless keyboard using Bluetooth, there should be a barcode scanner that also connects via Bluetooth and supports keyboard input emulation. By doing so, you will be able to connect the barcode scanner while maintaining the connection with the host PC in debug mode.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I will look into it, thanks